# Unity Mobile - How to make fluid swipe to move movement?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I am working on a personal project, and I had this idea for a movement that I don't know to realize. So the project(game) is for phone, and what I want to, is to when I swap in a direction, that vector becomes its closest axis (ex: 70 degrees will be (0,1) while 35 will be (1,0)). So when I get a swipe, I want my character to move in that direction. MAIN ISSUE is I don't know how to make him dash to that location. I know how to make him TELEPORT, but not how to make him DASH. I tried going for Vector2.Lerp, but it is a bit buggy and feels like character does not react on time. Here is the script:

```
private void Update()
{
    if (gameObject.GetComponent<OnDeath>().isDead == false)
    { 
        if (trigger)
         {
            fractionOfWayThere += 0.1f;
            transform.position=Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, finish, fractionOfWayThere);
            isMoving = true;
        }
        if ((Vector2)transform.position == finish)
        {
            isMoving = false;
            animator.SetBool("isMoving", false);
        }
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                startPos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
            }

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
            {
                endPos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
                destination = endPos - startPos;

                 if (Mathf.Abs(destination.x) > Mathf.Abs(destination.y))
                {
                    destination = new Vector2(Funkcija(destination.x), 0);
                }
                if (Mathf.Abs(destination.x) < Mathf.Abs(destination.y))
                {
                    destination = new Vector2(0, Funkcija(destination.y));
                }
                if (Mathf.Abs(destination.x) == Mathf.Abs(destination.y))
                {
                     destination = new Vector2(Funkcija(destination.x), 0);
                }
                finish = (Vector2)transform.position + destination.normalized;
                if (Physics2D.OverlapCircle(finish, 0.1f, spike) != null)
                 {
                    if (finish.x < transform.position.x)
                    {
                        sr.flipX = true;
                         }
                    else if (finish.x > transform.position.x)
                            sr.flipX = false;
                    trigger = true;
                    fractionOfWayThere = 0;
                    isMoving = true;
                    animator.SetBool("isMoving", true);
                }
                else
                {
                finish = transform.position;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Most of the code is getting the swipe into its axis and flipping sprite, only thing regarding the movement is this:

```
if (trigger)
         {
            fractionOfWayThere += 0.1f;
            transform.position=Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, finish, fractionOfWayThere);
            isMoving = true;
        }
```

Playtesting, this feels realy weird. I tried Vector2.MovePosition(), rb.AddForce() and rb.MovePosition. Any other way to do this, or even using those functionts I have not thought of? All feedback would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. Lerp is a good Start, but it's linear. A Dash would typically start instantly and slow down over time.
2. to achieve framerate independent movement, you should use [Time.deltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) in Update. It's neglectable in FixedUpdate as these occur at (almost) fixed timesteps.

You can achieve that by adding an [AnimationCurve](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCurve.html) to your code:

```
[...]
public AnimationCurve dashCurve = new AnimationCurve.Linear(0,0,1,1); // modify this in inspector!
[...]
if (trigger)
{
    fractionOfWayThere += 0.5f * Time.deltaTime; // fractionOfWayThere takes 0.5 second to grow from 0 to 1.


    transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, finish, dashCurve.Evaluate(fractionOfWayThere));
    isMoving = true;
}
```

Set up the AnimationCurve like this:

[image: Animation Curve for Dash]

Comment: Ok great, this works perfectly! What bothers me though,  is: Should I set  fractionOfWayThere =0 every time movement is called, or leave it as is?

Comment: Lerp clamps `t` between 0 and 1. So yes, reset `fractionOfWayThere` to 0 when ever you dash.